# vim: macro to insert line number with some maths

Tags: vim, macros

I've got a directory with more than 100 000 small files.
I'd like to put them into separate folders.

```
find mydir/ -type f | sort > tt.txt
vim tt.txt
```

Now I'd like for each line, to insert a number with this formulae:

(line number) + 50000 + ((line number/1000)*1000)

So the original file is something like:

```
abainville_55130_55001.htm
abancourt_59268_59001.htm
abbenans_25340_25003.htm
abergement-de-cuisery_71290_71001.htm
```

And should output:

```
51001 - abainville_55130_55001.htm
51002 - abancourt_59268_59001.htm
51003 - abbenans_25340_25003.htm
51004 - abergement-de-cuisery_71290_71001.htm
```

and so on until the 1000th line where

```
line  998 => 51000 - bannes_53340_53019.htm
line  999 => 51000 - bannieres_81500_81022.htm
line 1000 => 52000 - bannoncourt_55300_55027.htm
line 1001 => 52000 - banos_40500_40024.htm
line 1002 => 52000 - bans_39380_39037.htm
```

and after that I'll apply a macro to transform it to:

```
mv bannes_53340_53019.htm 51998/bannes_53340_53019.htm
mv bannieres_81500_81022.htm 51999/bannieres_81500_81022.htm
mv bannoncourt_55300_55027.htm 52000/bannoncourt_55300_55027.htm
mv banos_40500_40024.htm 52001/banos_40500_40024.htm
mv bans_39380_39037.htm 52002/bans_39380_39037.htm
```

(the last part is easy and *not the problem*, the problem is about maths).

I know there's something like but I can't find the solution to apply my maths:

```
:s/^/\=(line('.')+51000)/
```

Comment: You don't need `vim` for that.

Comment: Yes but I want to do it in vim for (1) learn something (2) share *here* the knowledge.

Comment: For your information, the solution with awk is `cat tt.txt | awk -F '/' '{  i=52000+(int(NR/1000)*1000); print "mv "$1"/"$2" "$1"/"i"/"$2 }' > uu.txt && source uu.txt` but I just want to know how I can do this with **`vim`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do the job in two steps, you could generate those `"mv..."` command lines with vim in one short, if you want to stick to vim.

try this line:

```
%s#.*$#\="mv ".submatch(0)." ".(line(".")+50000+((line(".")/1000)*1000)) . "/" . submatch(0)#
```

will generate something like: (`if the first line is on line number 1`)

```
mv abainville_55130_55001.htm 50001/abainville_55130_55001.htm
mv abancourt_59268_59001.htm 50002/abancourt_59268_59001.htm
mv abbenans_25340_25003.htm 50003/abbenans_25340_25003.htm
mv abergement-de-cuisery_71290_71001.htm 50004/abergement-de-cuisery_71290_71001.htm
```

Comment: How did you replace the `/` by the `#` character in vim? Or (maybe better) how would you write this with the `/`?

Comment: @OlivierPons You can use any other single byte character, e.g. `:s@..@..@ or :s;..;..; or :s#..#..#` you have `/` in replacement, (`(...)/1000`). so better use another character to surround the patterns.

Comment: Ok, so the first char just after the '`s`' is defined as the 'separator' for this command line?

Comment: @OlivierPons yes, check `:h :s`

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there. You can use the following command:

```
:%s/^/\=line('.')+51000 . " - "/
```

where `%` applies it to the whole file and `.` does string concatenation to get your spaced hyphen.

**Edit:**

In order to use `/` as part of the expression, you can change the delimiter character (see `:help E146`). For example, the following generates 51000 for 1000 lines, then 52000 for the next 1000 lines, and so on:

```
:s!^!\=50000 + (line('.') / 1000) * 1000 . " - "!
```

Comment: Your answer will only give (51000+line number). This is not what I'm asking for. I'm asking for (line number) + 50000 + ((line number/1000)*1000), which give *only* 51000 for 1000 lines, then 52000 for 1000 lines, then 53000 for 1000 lines, and so on...

Comment: @OlivierPons You do say this in the question, but that's not what your sample output looks like.